# Managed to fetch API and display JSON in console, need help displaying data

Tags: javascript, html, json, api

```js
var url = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=talksport&apiKey='YOUR_API_KEY';

          
var req = new Request(url);
fetch(req)
    .then(function(response) {
        var results = (response.json());
       
      
       
    console.log(results);

    })
```

Using a News API i am using this code to try and fetch articles based around sports for my website. So far from what I've tried I've managed to console.log the JSON file that I am fetching from the API. This returns an object with 10 articles inside which is what I was looking for. I however want to be able to console.log the data inside of the JSON object. I've looked at several YouTube/written tutorials to try and find my answer as well as the actual website that I got the API from, but they don't give out any more information and i'm at a loss. Any help here would be appreciated!

[Console Log Object IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMgEn.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! I suggest you take a little time to take the [tour] and particularly about which questions are on-topic. In theory you are supposed to ask a precise question with showing an attempt to solve the problem yourself. For your case, some people may want to help you but you should provide an HTML template for an article display to allow us to help you fill it with actual data, and also the article structure from your API response (open one of your 10 objects in your log for us to see what's inside). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

`response.json` returns a promise. You need to chain one more promise to get the data you are looking for.

Here is the code:

```
var url = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=talksport&apiKey='YOUR_API_KEY';


var req = new Request(url);
fetch(req)
    .then(function(response) {
       return response.json()
    }).then(function(jsonResponse){
      console.log(jsonResponse)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

@**Akshay Milmile**  is right. You have to resolve your promise
see the code:

```js
var YOUR_API_KEY = "";
var url = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=talksport&apiKey=' + YOUR_API_KEY;

          
var req = new Request(url);
fetch(req)
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
        console.log(results);

    }).then(function(jsonResponse){
      console.log(jsonResponse)
    })
```

But your error came from another line:

`var url = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?ources=talksport&apiKey='YOUR_API_KEY';`

If you want to keep it, you have to change it to:

`var url = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=talksport&apiKey=' + YOUR_API_KEY;`